# iOS mobile app certificate authority

Tags: ios, certificate, alamofire, ca, authority

I apologize in advance if i made a duplicate of this question. I'm working on a mobile app that communicates with an API on a .local domain. I'm stuck at trying to establish a secure connection (using Alamofire). I Tried to write a custom ServerTrustPolicy just as Alamofire wiki suggests, and include my certificate chain, but it always fails. The only way to get the app to connect is by configuring App Transport Security in .plist file and adding the domain as exception. Does anyone have experiance with using certificates trough alamofire with .local domains? Would really appreciate any advice. Thank you in advance.

This is my Alamofire.Manger:

static let sharedInstance: Manager = {

```
    var apiObject = ApiBaseService()

    //let domainName = apiObject.getDomain()
    let pathToCert = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("certca", ofType: "der")
    let localCertificate:NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathToCert!)!

    let serverTrustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.PinCertificates(
        certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle(),
        validateCertificateChain: true,
        validateHost: true
    )

    let value = GlobalConstants.APICallErrorLocations.actionsGetActions
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "test.ex01.local": serverTrustPolicy
    ]

    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.Manager.defaultHTTPHeaders
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = NSTimeInterval(12.0)


    return Manager(configuration: configuration,
    serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies))
    }()
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Kristian

EDIT:

The thing was TLS version was v1.0 which i discovered with this command:

openssl s_client -connect test.ex01.local:5000

After updating TLS version and including certificate chain in ServerTrustPolicy object, everything works.

Hope this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your certificate chain is not valid and is self-signed (assuming this is the case), then you MUST disable ATS for that host, or you'll never be able to use the Alamofire cert pinning logic. ATS will never even give Alamofire a chance to evaluate the cert chain.

The reason for this behavior is that ATS first evaluates the connection challenge before giving the `NSURLSessionDelegate` a chance to evaluate the challenge. If ATS evaluates the properties of the challenge and determines it should not trust the connection, it stops there and the request will not succeed. It doesn't call the `NSURLSessionDelegate` to give you a second chance to override it.

However, when you disable ATS, the first ATS checks no longer happen, and the challenge is sent to the `NSURLSessionDelegate` for evaluation which is where Alamofire kicks in.

Comment: It's an honor to have you answering my question :) So basically, if the security requirements for connecting via ATS are not met, it will never give it a chance. About the certificates...I created a Root CA (it signs other issued certificates) which is self signed, and when i manually install the certificate chain on an iphone, it connects trough safari web browser with no problems. Still, with the mobile app that's not the case. Is that what your assumption was? Any additional advice? Thank you so much.

Comment: If you install the Root CA cert as a root cert on iOS, you will most likely see the same behavior as macOS. If not, you could instead use something like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) to generate validate certs for free!

Answer (score 0):

AppTransportSecurity is used to list connections that you want that are not HTTPS. iOS blocks non HTTPS connections that are not in this list!

Comment: That is, infact, what i thought initially until this thing confused me (alamofire wiki): "With the addition of App Transport Security (ATS) in iOS 9, it is possible that using a custom ServerTrustPolicyManager with several ServerTrustPolicy objects will have no effect. If you continuously see CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806) errors, you have probably run into this problem. Apple's ATS system overrides the entire challenge system unless you configure the ATS settings in your app's plist to disable enough of it to allow your app to evaluate the server trust.